# How to implement a background thread using java.util.concurrent package?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

This is the code I used first but in latest Android version `AsyncTask` class is deprecated and
therefore it was not responding and then I used the `Thread` class but that class is also not working.
I want the same result as I was getting with the `AsyncTask` class.
I know that I have to use some executor class of java.util.concurrent package but don't know which and how to use it.
Please help me with this thing.

```
private static final String USGS_REQUEST_URL =
            "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2016-01-01&endtime=2016-05-02&minfelt=50&minmagnitude=5";

EarthquakeAsyncTask task = new EarthquakeAsyncTask();
        task.execute(USGS_REQUEST_URL);
private class EarthquakeAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Event> {

        @Override
        protected Event doInBackground(String... urls) {

            // Perform the HTTP request for earthquake data and process the response.
            Event result = Utils.fetchEarthquakeData(urls[0]);
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Event result) {
            // Update the information displayed to the user.
            updateUi(result);
        }
    }
```

```
private static final String USGS_REQUEST_URL =
            "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2016-01-01&endtime=2016-05-02&minfelt=50&minmagnitude=5";

earthquakeRunnable runnable = new earthquakeRunnable(USGS_REQUEST_URL);
        runnable.start();

private class earthquakeRunnable extends Thread{

            String urls;
            earthquakeRunnable(String url){
                this.urls = url;
            }
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Perform the HTTP request for earthquake data and process the response.
                Event result = Utils.fetchEarthquakeData(urls);
                // Update the information displayed to the user
                updateUi(result);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example of how you might use an ExecutorService within your Activity/Fragment:

```
// Create some member variables for the ExecutorService 
// and for the Handler that will update the UI from the main thread
ExecutorService mExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

// Create an interface to respond with the result after processing
public interface OnProcessedListener {
    public void onProcessed(Event result);
}

private void processInBg(final String url, final boolean finished){
    
    final OnProcessedListener listener = new OnProcessedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onProcessed(Event result){
            // Use the handler so we're not trying to update the UI from the bg thread
            mHandler.post(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    // Update the UI here
                    updateUi(result);
                    
                    // ...
                    
                    // If we're done with the ExecutorService, shut it down.
                    // (If you want to re-use the ExecutorService,
                    // make sure to shut it down whenever everything's completed
                    // and you don't need it any more.)
                    if(finished){
                        mExecutor.shutdown();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    
    Runnable backgroundRunnable = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            // Perform your background operation(s) and set the result(s)
            Event result = Utils.fetchEarthquakeData(url);
            
            // ...
            
            // Use the interface to pass along the result
            listener.onProcessed(result);
        }
    };
    
    mExecutor.execute(backgroundRunnable);
}
```

Then, wherever you need to trigger your background processing:

```
processInBg("some_url", true);
```

Depending on your situation, you'll want to customize your implementation of ExecutorService to better suit your needs.

Comment: Handler class is showing that it is deprecated and also all the variables u have declared are giving an error of declaring final to all the variables and if it is assigned to final then it cannot be assigned a new value.

Comment: thanks for the help just needed some declaration changes and the method was correct. Thank You!

Comment: I want to ask something else, what is the use of the handler class and handler class object????

Comment: My apologies. I was writing this on the fly and overlooked the final variable declarations. And yes, the Handler() constructor is deprecated. The constructor is supposed to be Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()). I've updated my answer to include these and to show how to respond with an interface.

Comment: The reason I included the Handler is because the UI must be updated from the main thread. It's one of the ways you can return to the main thread after running on a background thread.

Comment: @Sammy T Does the update on the main thread always only occur after the background thread work is complete?

Comment: @AJW In this example, the main thread update is set up to happen after the `listener.onProcessed()` interface callback is invoked. 
If you're performing a synchronous operation where the work will be completed before executing the next line, you would invoke the callback after all of your synchronous statements. If you're performing an asynchronous operation, you would most likely just use whatever callback is provided by that operation.