# My app doesn't work when the data cleared from settings

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, settings, splash-screen

I want to reset the app data for testing.
so I went to the Settings and navigated to my app and cleared the data.
But then When I open the app, it didn't work the first time . then I close the app and open it again then it worked properly.
How to solve this issue here?. Any sort of advice ?

**Edit:** "Didn't work" means the app opens the splash and freezes and the intent doesn't execute because of PiracyChecker's sharedpreference returns false

My app is a release version.
I use [PiracyChecker 1.2.8](https://github.com/javiersantos/PiracyChecker) in my code

Here's my launching code :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    new PiracyChecker(this).addAppToCheck(apps)
            .enableGooglePlayLicensing(BuildConfig.LICENSE)
            .enableInstallerId(InstallerID.GOOGLE_PLAY)
            .enableUnauthorizedAppsCheck()
            .blockIfUnauthorizedAppUninstalled("pref1","pref2")
            .enableStoresCheck()
            .enableFoldersCheck()
            .enableEmulatorCheck(false)
            .enableDebugCheck()
            .display(Display.ACTIVITY)
            .saveResultToSharedPreferences("pref1", "pref3")
            .start();

 }


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences pr1 = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("pref1",0);

    if(pr1!=null && pr1.getBoolean("pref3",false))
    {

        startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
        finish();

    }
}
```

Comment: "When I open the app, it didn't work the first time" -- please explain in detail what "didn't work" means. For example, are you crashing? If so, edit your question to provide the stack trace.

Comment: @CommonsWare Oh sorry I edited it, lack of expressing the situation

Comment: Hazard a guess the window system is from javax.swing library, it requires being wrapped in a special swing thread executor for startup of a windowing app. See the java and Android tutorials for startup thread execution of the main window. The wrapping code is the same for all programs anyone writes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using [ExecutorService](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService) after some searching and thanks to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64736616/18407518)... Now I can clear the data from settings and the app works fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).